# PrimeNG p-tree filter Issue

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

Not showing child nodes, we have to manually open tree to see the filtered result.

in html file:

```
<p-tree [value]="filesTree2" filter="true" selectionMode="single" filterMode="strict"></p-tree>
```

In component.ts :

```
filesTree2: TreeNode[] =
[
    {
        "label": "Documents",
        "key": "Documents",
        "data": "Documents Folder",
        "expandedIcon": "fa fa-folder-open",
        "collapsedIcon": "fa fa-folder",
        "children": [{
                "label": "Work",
                "key": "Work",
                "data": "Work Folder",
                "expandedIcon": "fa fa-folder-open",
                "collapsedIcon": "fa fa-folder",
                "children": [{"label": "Expenses.doc", "key": "Expenses.doc", "icon": "fa fa-file-word-o", "data": "Expenses Document"}, {"label": "Resume.doc", "key": "Resume.doc", "icon": "fa fa-file-word-o", "data": "Resume Document"}]
            },
            {
                "label": "Home",
                "key": "Home",
                "data": "Home Folder",
                "expandedIcon": "fa fa-folder-open",
                "collapsedIcon": "fa fa-folder",
                "children": [{"label": "Invoices.txt", "key": "Invoices.txt", "icon": "fa fa-file-word-o", "data": "Invoices for this month"}]
            }]
    },
    {
        "label": "Pictures",
        "key": "Pictures",
        "data": "Pictures Folder",
        "expandedIcon": "fa fa-folder-open",
        "collapsedIcon": "fa fa-folder",
        "children": [
            {"label": "barcelona.jpg", "key": "barcelona.jpg", "icon": "fa fa-file-image-o", "data": "Barcelona Photo"},
            {"label": "logo.jpg", "key": "logo.jpg", "icon": "fa fa-file-image-o", "data": "PrimeFaces Logo"},
            {"label": "primeui.png", "key": "primeui.png", "icon": "fa fa-file-image-o", "data": "PrimeUI Logo"}]
    },
    {
        "label": "Movies",
        "key": "Movies",
        "data": "Movies Folder",
        "expandedIcon": "fa fa-folder-open",
        "collapsedIcon": "fa fa-folder",
        "children": [{
                "label": "Al Pacino",
                "key": "Al Pacino",
                "data": "Pacino Movies",
                "children": [{"label": "Scarface", "key": "Scarface", "icon": "fa fa-file-video-o", "data": "Scarface Movie"}, {"label": "Serpico", "key": "Serpico", "icon": "fa fa-file-video-o", "data": "Serpico Movie"}]
            },
            {
                "label": "Robert De Niro",
                "key": "Robert De Niro",
                "data": "De Niro Movies",
                "children": [{"label": "Goodfellas", "key": "Goodfellas", "icon": "fa fa-file-video-o", "data": "Goodfellas Movie"}, {"label": "Untouchables", "key": "Untouchables", "icon": "fa fa-file-video-o", "data": "Untouchables Movie"}]
            }]
    }
];
```

1. when i tried to search for **"Expenses"** in search filter tree should open and show the result which is not working .
2. Present Result. 
    [image: Tried to search for Exp and tree is not opened]
3. Expected result. 
    [image: Expected result]
4. Even i tried with Lenient Filter Mode and Strict Filter Mode with that also no result.

please help me,thank you

Comment: What is your primeng version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a PrimeNG version issue.

**In version 7.1.3 , it is not expanding**
[image: In version 7.1.3 , it is not expanding]

**In version 8.1.1 (Latest stable version), it is expanding**
[image: In version 8.1.1 (Latest stable version), it is expanding]

Check your package.json file and update primeng dependency.

```
"dependencies": {
  //...
  "primeng": "^8.1.1",
  "primeicons": "^2.0.0"
},
```

For more details:

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-7.1.3/#/tree

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/tree

Comment: Hi Binara Thambugala thanks for your reply, I want to be collapsed in at first time only during search in filter it should open

Comment: What is your primeng version?show me your package.json file

Comment: Hi @santhosh if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59680820/12609535) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I was facing the same issue, I observed my json did not have the key. After adding, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the way to replicate this issue. But not able to find any issue with this code.

- I am using Primeng Version 7.

I fixed typo in your json `"lakeybel": "Scarface"` it should be `"key": "Scarface"`. Even With typo it is working fine.

Just try again with correct JSON and use `<p-tree>` as given in documentation
`<p-tree [value]="filesTree2" [filter]="true" [filterMode]="strict"></p-tree>`.

Also check if you see any console error or warning.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. yeah i changed typo "lakeybel" to "key" and used p-tree which is given in documentation event i don't see any errors in console, still this doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a key for every item in your tree
check this solution with primeng 11.3.0
[**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-treeselection-demo-2pnk19?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)